# Google Apps Script - Tweet Approver

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been following the guide found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial

About creating a twitter app.

I've been looking at the part below:

```
To get started, copy this spreadsheet containing the script for this tutorial. Once you've got your own copy of the spreadsheet, open it and you will notice the spreadsheet will be empty; that is intentional, as we won't be using any of the spreadsheet's cells in this tutorial.The first thing you need to do is publish your script as a service. To do this, open the script editor by clicking Tools > Script Editor... In the new window, click Publish > Publish as Service...
```

This doesn't actually work at all.

If I open the spreadsheet and click Tools > Script Editor.. I'm taken to the script wizard. It then give me the option of creating a new script. The script can only be published to gallery, or as a web app. Where is the publish as service option?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I checked on the tutorial page and it seems indeed that the template spreadsheet has not script included...

But the full code is still published at the end of the same page so you could copy/paste the full code in the script editor (choose new code from the wizard and delete everything in there ) and start from there.

About the *"publish as service"* this is the old name of what is now known as **deploy as webapp**, the procedure is slightly different and is described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps), you will need to first save a version (manage version in the file menu) and you will get 2 urls, one for development and one for use, both will run from your browser starting with the `doGet()` function.

The remaining part of the tutorial about initialisation and authorization from the spreadsheet menu is unchanged, just follow the tutorial instructions.

Hoping it will help you,